# Excluding Specific Fields from Profile Builder Registration Form

Tags: custom-field, forms, user-registration, buddypress, profiles

I understand that in order to add extra fields to the default WordPress user, one must use a plugin such as Profile Builder. Such plugins also provide short-codes for linking signup and login forms into a desired page.

The problem is - I want to add fields to the default user and NOT have them appear in the registration form. For example, I want to add an "upload your avatar" option or "about you" field to the user.. but I don't want such fields to appear in the registration page since they are unnecessary for creating an account - the user can fill them in later - if he wants. I know I can label such fields as "not required" and the user will not be compelled to fill them in on registration - but I don't want such fields to appear at all in the registration page - I want to keep it as concise and simple as possible.

**How can one achieve that using Profile Builder? I have searched for add-ons but with no luck.**

Would you recommend another profile manager plugin that handles this issue better?

NB - I have 3 main tasks at hand

- Extend the default user profile with custom fields
- Enable a profile management system to link up later with BuddyPress
- Create custom Login & Registration form pages.. (with custom selected fields only)

and it seems like Profile Builder has the ability to do all of that - but the inescapable issue is that the logic between these 3 phases is interlaced and thus hinders the flexibility of design and makes the entire thing.. less modular.

I don't mind at all using a different plugin for each of these "3 phases" as long as these plugins integrate well together and also integrate nicely with BuddyPress.